# KeyError in Python BaseHTTPHandler while parsing HTTP GET request

Tags: python-3.x, get, keyerror, basehttpserver

```
    def do_GET(self):
        logging.info("GET request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n", str(self.path), str(self.headers))
        self._set_response()
        params = parse_qs(urlparse(self.path).query)


    global yt1, yt2, yt3, yt4 

    yt1 = params['a']  
    yt2 = params['s']  
    yt3 = params['d']  
    yt4 = params['f'] 
    print(yt1,yt2,yt3,yt4)

    self.wfile.write("GET request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))`
```

URL: http://localhost:8086/?a=b&s=t&d=e&f=g

I am receiving correct output but getting a KeyError.

**KeyError: 'a'**

the same thing happened with this code also.

```
try:
    params = dict([p.split('=') for p in parsed_path[4].split('&')])
    print(params)
 except:
    params = {}
```